# Get access to req.user outside of google auth routes

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-authentication

I am using passportjs google auth to login users and right now I am trying to get access to req.user in another route instead of my google auth route.
  The reason why i want access to req.user is because I am trying to figure out who is currently logged as the current user in another route, lets call the other route userRoute.js. 
 I know I can get access to req.user inside:

```
router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "success", user: req.user });
  }
});
```

however, I need access to req.user in another route. How can I achieve this?

my google auth route

```
//Google auth routes
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: [`profile`, `email`] })
);

router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect:
      environment === "development"
        ? "http://localhost:3000"
        : "https://asdasdasd.heroku.com",
    failureRedirect: "/login/failed",
    session: true,
  })
);

router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "success", user: req.user });
  }
});

router.get("/login/failed", (req, res) => {
  res.send("login failed");
});

router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect(
    environment === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : "https://asdasdasd.herokuapp.com"
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Passport doesn't provide the session management, you will need to store the user login success in a session management system like `express-session` or a jwt.

Typical workflow for express-session

1. On login, after passport, store the user id in req.session.userId
2. On any other route until the cookie is expired, access the user Id via req.session.userId